# Pathria's number of states asymptotic estimation

Tags: thermodynamics, asymptotics

I'm seeking for a mathematical grounding behind one trick employed in "Statistical Mechanics" book by R. Pathria and P. Beale to calculate the entropy $S(N,V,E)$ of an ideal monoatomic gas by counting the number of consistent microstates. From an expression for "the energy eigenvalues for a free, nonrelativistic particle", this comes down to counting the positive-integral solutions of the equation
$$\sum_{r=1}^{3N}n_r^2=\frac{8mV^{2/3}E}{h^2}=E^{*}.$$
The number of such solutions $\Omega_N(E^*)$ equals to the number of positive-integral lattice points lying on the surface of a $3N$-dimensional sphere of radius $\sqrt{E^*}$ and is highly irregular function of $E^*$. So they consider the function $\Sigma_N(E^*)$, the number of positive-integral lattice points *lying on or within* the surface of a $3N$-dimensional sphere of radius $\sqrt{E^*}$. It's much less irregular and asymptotically equals to the volume of the mentioned region, that is,
$$\Sigma_N(E^*)\approx\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3N}\left\{\frac{\pi^{3N/2}}{(3N/2)!}{E^*}^{3N/2}\right\}.$$
Now the trick: instead of demanding energies to sum up exactly to $E$, allow some deviation $\Delta$ from it and count all microstates with total energy lying between $\left(E-\frac{1}{2}\Delta\right)$ and $\left(E+\frac{1}{2}\Delta\right)$. It is claimed then that this number $\Gamma_N(E^*;\Delta)$ can be asymptotically estimated by differentiation of the estimation of $\Sigma_N(E^*)$, namely $\Gamma_N(E^*;\Delta)\approx\Sigma_N^{\prime}(E^*)\Delta$, and taking logarithm then eliminates the dependence on $\Delta$ and yields a nice expression for the entropy.

At the same time, asymptotical equivalences in general can not be differentiated. Also, the allowed values for $\Delta$ are unclear. On one hand, $\Delta\ll E$ must hold. On the other hand, it must not tend to zero as the number of microstates $\Sigma_N(E^*)$ is still not differentiable. In fact, it's even not continuous and entirely consists of jumps at integral values of $E^*$. Authors provide an estimation $\Delta/E=O(N^{-1/2})$ without any explanation and reference. Can anyone confirm that the above reasoning is mathematically correct for this specific case?